# Iterate through a doubly linked list?

Tags: java

I am trying to pull nodes out of a doubly linked list and figured the best way to be to iterate through it, I did an enhanced for loop and it is complaining 
"for-each not appliable to expression type required:array or java.lang.iterable found:doublylinkedlist"

So how do i even go about pulling nodes out of this list then?

Here is my code:

```
public static void gainLoss(){
        //variables
         int sellPrice;
        DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();      

        //traverse through the list
         for (Node n : list) {

         }
}
```

Comment: Is DoublyLinkedList your custom data structure ?

Comment: add source of your DoublyLinkedList class

Comment: `DoublyLinkedList` is neither a collection class from Java, nor something coming from de facto 3rd party lib.  How do we suppose to know what's that and be able to guess the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your data structure with a for-each loop, you have to implement the interface [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) (and implement an underlying iterator).

Answer (score 0):

If `DoublyLinkedList` class is from [Algorithms, 4th Edition](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/DoublyLinkedList.java.html) than:

```
    DoublyLinkedList<DoublyLinkedList.Node> list = new DoublyLinkedList<DoublyLinkedList.Node>();
    for(DoublyLinkedList.Node node : list) {
        // do whatever you want            
    }
```

Comment: It's not because the OP's compiler message says theirs is not Iterable.

Comment: DoublyLinkedList<Item> implements Iterable<Item> - see the link in my answer